# Localstorage data flush out when app kill in Android 5.0.2

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working on cordova app which stored login details in localStorage so user not need to login again when he/she open app again.

It's working with kitkat(4.4.4) and also working with lollipop(5.1) versions.

But it's not working for lollipop (5.0.2).

Can any give my guidance about this?

I read some forum about this. Some say it's bug with this Android version 5.0.2.

Then after if some on have solution for it, then it's much appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: by "local storage" you mean preferences??

Comment: no i am using backbone-localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with Android webView.

I had update for Android webView and i just updated it and it's working.

So any one have same issue just update webView for particular device if update available.

Thanks.

Comment: You can update webview like update normal app from appstore.